# FPV system with camera synchronized to IMU

Tags: quadcopters, first-person-view, camera, imu

I'm looking for a drone who has an IMU synchronized to a camera. Global shutter would be nice but I would even tolerate rolling shutter if it's time stamps lock to the IMU. Does a hobby priced commercial solution exist?

I can build my own with a pi and a global shutter camera but I would prefer using an existing solution.